# Restore page after deleting it from trash

Tags: trash

I accidentally deleted a page in my trash area, is there a way I can restore it? I can no longer find the page.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a backup of your database then most probably your page is unfortunately gone forever. You could try contacting your hosting provider and ask if they have a backup stored somewhere.